# Escaped asterisk/query mark do not escape when using leading wildcard in Edismax

Tags: solr, escaping, wildcard, edismax

I'm trying to find documents containing asterisks/query marks in Solr text field using Edismax parser. Everything works perfectly when I search for usual text (`fq={!edismax}textfield:*sometext*`) or even for any other [special Lucene character](http://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs/versions/3_4_0/queryparsersyntax.html#Escaping%20Special%20Characters) using escaping (`fq={!edismax}textfield:*\~*`).

However when searching for `*` (`fq={!edismax}textfield:*\**`) or `?` (`fq={!edismax}textfield:*\?*`) these characters seem not to be escaped, since all documents are returned. I try also [URL encoding](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp) for escaped characters (like `\%2A` instead of `\*`), however the result is the same.

The problem appear to concern leading wildcards only, since `fq={!edismax}textfield:\**` and `fq={!edismax}textfield:\?*` return correct results, but `fq={!edismax}textfield:*\*` and `fq={!edismax}textfield:*\?` do not (as well as `fq={!edismax}textfield:*sometext\*` etc.).

How is it possible to search for `*`/`?` using Edismax with leading asterisk wildcard?

Answer (score 0):

Quoting the asterisk works for me. This query finds two books in my index with a standalone asterisk in the title:

```
title:"*"
```

Here is the title of one of them: "Be * Know * Do, Adapted from the Official Army Leadership Manual".

I'm using a edismax with Solr 3.3.

Comment: I would work for me if I used tokenizer like WhitespaceTokenizerFactory. However I need searching for strict coincidence of phrases and use KeywordTokenizerFactory. Therefore to find a part of field text I have to use wildcards.

Comment: You should be able to get strict coincidence of phrases without treating each field value as a single token. Doing regexes against tokens is essentially a full table scan. This is guaranteed to not scale. I recommend a different approach.